I broke my WSL, Cant seem to figure out how to repair it
So, I had WSL running on Win11 but I am a little confused because I had Ubuntu installed and I was working in the directory at /var/www/html/
I think I broke it because (not 100% sure here) I had an Ubuntu 24 .ISO file in my downloads directory inside a folder called Ubuntu or Ubuntu_24. I think the Ubuntu instal was using that .ISO to run maybe? I removed it to free up space and then when I went back to Ubuntu CLI it returned the error below.
I can't remember what the directory in Downloads was named. I tried putting it back but things remain broken.
Where do I find the "kernel=C:\wsl\myCustomKernel" file? Is it even a file?  I don't much about Kenrels. The relationship between Linux/Ubuntu and Windows 11 baffles me...
I use Ubuntu on the regular and do lots of server admin in Linux so I'm familiar with Linux distros but I'm not sure how I broke this. Was it removed the .ISO file for Ubuntu? I don't know.
But now it's broken it won't run and I can't reinstall it because it says it is already installed. I have work there that I'd prefer not to lose. It's only 1 day's work so I can redo it but if I can fix it I'd prefer that.
mikec@Mikes_Yoga MINGW64 /c
$ wsl --install
Ubuntu is already installed.
Launching Ubuntu...
wsl: Unknown key 'wsl2.pageReporting' in C:\Users\mikec\.wslconfig:23
The custom kernel specified in C:\Users\mikec\.wslconfig was not found: 'C:\wsl\myCustomKernel'.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/WSL_E_CUSTOM_KERNEL_NOT_FOUND
Press any key to continue...
The operation completed successfully.
mikec@Mikes_Yoga MINGW64 /c
$  

I have a .wslconfig in C:\Users\mikec.wslconfig
Any tips on where to put the kernel or how to resolve the missing kernel error would be appreciated!

C:\Users\mikec\.wslconfig this config file has specified the location for your custom kernel as C:\wsl\myCustomKernel. Where myCustomKernel is the filename of your custom kernel. Take note that the filename does not use a filename extension (suffix). I recommend to adjust the settings within the config file to your desires.

hey, thanks. So where do I find the kernel?
